# R code iteration

Tags: r, iteration

My goal is to generate this vector in R using `iter`:

```
0 + 1 = 1,

1 + 2 = 3,

3 + 3 = 6,

6 + 4 = 10
```

I tried the code below, but it didn't give me the right numbers:

```
iter <- 4
w_vector <- rep(0, iter)
for(i in 1:iter) {w_vector[i] <-sum(i, i-1)
                  print(w_vector[i])
}
```

I'll truly appreciate it if you can help me fix my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
w_vector <- cumsum(seq(iter))
w_vector
# [1]  1  3  6 10
```

Otherwise, using a `for` loop, your code should look something like:

```
iter <- 4
w_vector <- rep(0, iter)
w_vector[1] <- 1
for(i in 2:iter) {
  w_vector[i] <- w_vector[i-1] + i
}
w_vector
# [1]  1  3  6 10
```

Comment: And for something between the `for` loop and `cumsum` (in case you want to apply similar logic to more complicated problems) look at the `Reduce` function.