# R code iteration blues

Tags: r, iteration

I am very new to R, trying to use it to visualize things.  To make the story short, I'm exploring a conjecture I have on the economic theory of public goods.  (I'm in my mid 50s, so bear with me.)

As far as R is concerned, I need to create a matrix with two vectors, one with E(W)/max(W), and the 2nd vector with stdev(W)/E(W).  The trick is that the sample space of W, my r.v., keeps expanding by 1.  To make this clearer, here's the probability distribution of W, the first 4 iterations:

W p
0 2/3
1 1/3

W p
0 3/6
1 2/6
2 1/6

W p
0 4/10
1 3/10
2 2/10
3 1/10

W p
0 5/15
1 4/15
2 3/15
3 2/15
4 1/15

...

I need to iterate this 20 times or so.  Of course, I could do this manually, by copying, pasting, and then manually adjusting simple code, but it'd be too bulky and ugly looking, and I'm a bit concerned about --- you know --- elegance.

With good help from this community, I learned how to program R to generate the denominator of the probabilities:

[R code iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586372/r-code-iteration/)

I thought (foolishly) I could take it from there, but after a few hours scratching my bald head, I'm still stuck without knowing how to get what I want.  It's about my not understanding well how to program less simple procedures that iterate.  :/

I'll appreciate any help, especially clues setting me on the right track.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're just diving out by the sum; and sum of 1 to k is k*(k+1)/2. So...

```
R>k <- 3
R>k:1 / (k^2 + k)*2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you want a matrix of 20 or so rows with each row being the values of your two requested quantities given that the distribution has `max(W) = N` values.

```
t(vapply(seq_len(20) + 1, function(N) {
  W <- seq(N, 1) / (N * (N + 1) / 2) # create your distribution w/ 20 values
  E <- function(pdf) sum((seq_along(pdf) - 1) * pdf)
  c(E(W) / max(W), sqrt(E((W - E(W))^2)) / E(W))
}, numeric(2)))
```

Comment: I appreciate the replies.  With your code, Robert, I am not getting the results I get manually (which I trust).  So I'm going to have to work a little to decipher the code.  I'm not supposed to say 'thanks,' but thanks!

Comment: I think there may be a bug in his variance calculation.